# Attendance: Get time_in and time_out of flexible schedule Employees

Tags: mysql, sql, database, report

From the given schema below, I'd like to query the daily time in/out of the employees on my database.

Note: Employee schedules are flexible,  they can work on night shift or day shift (as you can see with employee #1).

**Schema: Attendances table**

```
| id | employee_id | timedata            | in_out |
|----|-------------|---------------------|--------|
| 1  | 1           | 2017-06-08 13:51:02 | IN     | <- night shift ( inserted: 2017-06-08)
| 2  | 1           | 2017-06-09 01:10:04 | OUT    | <- actual time_out (inserted: 2017-06-09)
| 3  | 1           | 2017-06-09 14:11:40 | IN     | 
| 4  | 1           | 2017-06-09 19:41:26 | OUT    |
| 5  | 2           | 2017-06-08 09:25:17 | IN     |
| 6  | 2           | 2017-06-08 20:44:14 | OUT    |
| 7  | 2           | 2017-06-09 11:35:00 | IN     |
| 8  | 2           | 2017-06-09 20:36:06 | OUT    |
```

This is the query i've done so far:

```
SELECT employee_id, 
       DATE(timedata) as attendance_date,
       MIN(IF(in_out='IN',timedata,NULL)) AS time_in, 
       MAX(IF(in_out='OUT',timedata,NULL)) AS time_out
FROM attendances
GROUP BY employee_id,DATE(timedata)
```

The problem with this query is that I can't get the time_out of the night shift transactions. this is the **Output:**

```
| employee_id | attendance_date | time_in             | time_out            |
|-------------|-----------------|---------------------|---------------------|
| 1           | 2017-06-08      | 2017-06-08 13:51:02 | NULL                |
| 2           | 2017-06-08      | 2017-06-08 11:25:17 | 2017-06-08 20:44:14 |
| 2           | 2017-06-09      | 2017-06-09 11:35:00 | 2017-06-09 20:36:06 |
| 1           | 2017-06-09      | 2017-06-09 14:11:40 | 2017-06-09 19:41:26 |
```

here's my
**Desired Output**

```
| employee_id | attendance_date | time_in             | time_out            |
|-------------|-----------------|---------------------|---------------------|
| 1           | 2017-06-08      | 2017-06-08 13:51:02 | 2017-06-09 01:10:04 |
| 2           | 2017-06-08      | 2017-06-08 09:25:17 | 2017-06-08 20:44:14 |
| 1           | 2017-06-09      | 2017-06-09 14:11:40 | 2017-06-09 19:41:26 |
| 2           | 2017-06-09      | 2017-06-09 11:35:00 | 2017-06-09 20:36:06 |
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question would be hard to handle without the use of analytic functions, which MySQL does not support out of the box.  However, we can simulate `ROW_NUMBER` using session variables.  One approach here would be to group `IN` and `OUT` by their juxtaposition in the table with regard to time ascending.  Consider the following query:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @emp_id = NULL;

SELECT
    t.employee_id,
    DATE(MAX(CASE WHEN in_out = 'IN'  THEN timedata END)) AS attendance_date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN in_out = 'IN'  THEN timedata END) AS time_in,
    MAX(CASE WHEN in_out = 'OUT' THEN timedata END) AS time_out
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        @row_number:=CASE WHEN @emp_id = employee_id THEN @row_number + 1 ELSE 0 END AS rn,
        TRUNCATE(@row_number / 2, 0) AS rn_grp,
        @emp_id:=employee_id
    FROM Attendances
    ORDER BY employee_id, timedata
) t
GROUP BY t.employee_id, t.rn_grp;
```

To see how this works, the row number I generated would leave your original table looking like the following:

```
| id | employee_id | timedata            | in_out | rn_grp |
|----|-------------|---------------------|--------|--------|
| 1  | 1           | 2017-06-08 13:51:02 | IN     | 0      |
| 2  | 1           | 2017-06-09 01:10:04 | OUT    | 0      |
| 3  | 1           | 2017-06-09 14:11:40 | IN     | 1      |
| 4  | 1           | 2017-06-09 19:41:26 | OUT    | 1      |
| 5  | 2           | 2017-06-08 09:25:17 | IN     | 0      |
| 6  | 2           | 2017-06-08 20:44:14 | OUT    | 0      |
| 7  | 2           | 2017-06-09 11:35:00 | IN     | 1      |
| 8  | 2           | 2017-06-09 20:36:06 | OUT    | 1      |
```

It should be clear now that we can group by the `employee_id` and the `rn_grp` column, and then just use the pivot query approach in your original question.

Note that this approach might not work if employee data could, for example, have an `IN` value without a corresponding `OUT` value.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 2):

You can use self join to combine time_in with time_out where time_out is after  time_in. Then just group it by time_in and pick only first time_out:

```
select employee_id, attendance_date,  time_in, MIN(time_out) time_out from (
   select A.id id, DATE(A.timedata) attendance_date, A.employee_id employee_id, A.timedata time_in, A.in_out, B.timedata time_out
   from attendances A
   left join attendances B
       on A.employee_id = B.employee_id
          and A.timedata < B.timedata
          and B.in_out = 'OUT'    
   where A.in_out = 'IN'
) AB
group by employee_id, attendance_date, time_in
```